# mvc3 combobox default selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using this approach using viewmodel for manipulating values inside combo boxes. Now, I'm struggle to select as default value actual selected value used in create action, not the first one from combo.  I know this is fourth parameter in `SelectList` but I do not know how to use actual  `UserGroupId` cause it's give me an error when using like these

```
var model = new UserViewModel 
    { 
        UserGroups = new SelectList(GetAllUsers(), "UserId", "Name", UserGroupId) 
    } 
    return View(model);
```

---

```
 public class UserViewModel 
    { 
        public int UserGroupId { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserGroups { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: look at this answer, i should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118706/building-a-dropdownlist-in-the-model/12118726#12118726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var model = new UserViewModel 
{ 
    // preselct an item in the dropdown whose value equals 5
    // This means that inside your `GetAllUsers()` collection you must
    // have an element with UserId=5 and this element will automatically be
    // preselcted. Here you could put any value of course
    UserGroupId = 5,
    UserGroups = new SelectList(GetAllUsers(), "UserId", "Name") 
};
return View(model);
```

and in your view:

```
@model UserViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UserGroupId, Model.UserGroups)
```

Comment: Do I need to send selected value if I set the property value correctly on create action ?

Comment: If by *create action* you mean the POST action to which you are submitting the form, then this action would take the view model as argument. If you are talking about the GET action then it will depend on where do you want this default value to come from. If you want the user to be able to provide it in the url, like for example `/create/123` then you could have your GET action take this default value as action argument indeed. But once again everything will depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So, If I understand you, if http post create action properly set value I either way should provide selected value inside SelectList on Edit http get action ?

Comment: No, I don't think you understood me. The POST action will get the selected value from the view model it takes as parameter and the dropdown will keep its selection. In the GET action you need to specify this default value which could come either as action parameter or from some other data source.

Answer (score 0):

As for the 4th parameter, it needs to be an actual instance that is part of the collection returned by GetAllUsers()

For example:

```
var users = GetAllUsers();
var defaultUser = users[0];
var model = new UserViewModel 
{ 
     UserGroups = new SelectList(users, "UserId", "Name", defaultUser) 
};

return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to manually build your SelectList rather than using the SelectList constructor.  That will give you the control you need over handling the "UserId" and the "Name".  This also addresses the issue of how to add an integer record id to the select list.

Lets start with a method that builds and returns a `List<SelectListItem>`

```
public static List<SelectListItem> UserGroups(int userGroupId, int selectedUserId)
{
    var userGroupsQuery = from u in dbContext.Users
                          where u.UserGroupId == userGroupId
                          select u;

    var userSelectList= new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var user in userGroupsQuery.Users)
    {
        userSelectList.Add(
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = userGroup.Name,
                Value = userGroup.UserId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Selected = (user.UserId == selectedUserId)
            };
    }

    return userSelectList;
}
```

Now we have a select list that we can use so lets use it in our action method.

```
int selectedUserId = 1000;
int userGroupId = 5;

var userViewModel = new UserViewModel
{
    UserGroups = ListLookup.UserGroups(userGroupId, selectedUserId)
}

return View(userViewModel);
```

And then in the view.

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserId", Model.Users)
```

The key here is that the `Value` property in the select list must be a string, not an integer.   Also note  that you cannot call to string inside a lambda expression by default (hence the use of a foreach loop).  Most SelectList examples do not show how to use the `Selected` property to select a particular value in the SelectList item.

I hope this helps :)